# NHibernate N+1 select : architectural solution?

Tags: nhibernate, architecture

Considering the following "database" :

```
Post -> User
```

The entities :

```
class User
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

class Post
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}
```

And the following service Layer:

```
class UserService
{
    IRepositoryUsers repositoryUsers;

    IList<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return this.repositoryUsers.GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

When I want to print all users, with associated post count, I get (no surprise here) a N+1 select problem, as for each line, it will create a select to get the posts for the users.

Now here is my question : what is the "best" way to handle this, as there are some cases when I don't want to eager load each user's posts.

Should I create as many methods in my repository (and service) to match those scenarios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to have a fetching strategy for every scenario in which you need to retrieve the data. 
This [blog post](http://www.codeinsanity.com/2009/02/fetching-strategy-and-adaptive-domain.html) explains a possible solution for this type of problem, the author uses his own version of IRepository but you use the same ideas in your repository (or check out his [NCommon](http://ncommon.codeplex.com/) project to get some inspiration)

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's a few ways to get rid of a Select N+1 problem. With NHibernate, one of my favorite ways to do this is to use the Criteria API, which is very sensible and well thought-out.

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Fruit))            // Get me some fruit.
    .SetFetchMode("CitrusType", FetchMode.Eager) // Just get this one field.
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Basket", 47))            // Only fruit that are in this basket.
    .List();                                     // Get 'em all.
```

To read more about this and other strategies, I recommend a look at this [interesting blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/02/CombatingTheSelectN1ProblemInNHibernate.aspx).

Comment: So I have to create as many "GetThisThingForThisScenario" methods ?